# Left Outer Join with Unique Set of Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join, window-functions

I have a table A with two fields

```
SETID   SEL_GROUP
KICAE   AA_01DBA
KICAE   AA_02DHM
KICAE   AA_03DML
KICAE   AA_03DMO
KICAE   AA_05CAO
KICAE   AA_05CGA
```

Another Table with Two Fields

```
SETID  COURSELIST
KICAE   110011000
KICAE   110011200
KICAE   110011500
KICAE   110011530
KICAE   110021000
KICAE   110021200
KICAE   110021500
KICAE   110021530

................
```

In table two the CourseList last 4 Characters repeat From Position 3 to Position 5 Sequentially.

I want the output to be

```
SETID  SEL_GROUP   COURSE_LIST
KICAE   AA_01DBA   110011000
KICAE   AA_01DBA   110011200
KICAE   AA_01DBA   110011500
KICAE   AA_01DBA   110011530
KICAE   AA_02DHM   110021000    ---------The Sequence Changes When the SEL_GROUP Changes
KICAE   AA_02DHM   110021200
KICAE   AA_02DHM   110021500
KICAE   AA_02DHM   110021530
```

Comment: What about the other six rows in the first table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select t2.setid, t1.sel_group, t2.courselist
from (select t2.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by setid order by substr(courselist, 1, 5)) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 join
     (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by setid order by sel_group) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum and t2.setid = t1.setid;
```

This enumerates the groups in `table2` based on the first five characters in the course list.  It then enumerates the rows in `table1` and uses that for joining.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select a.setid, a.sel_group, b.courselist
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by setid order by sel_group) rn
    from a
) a
inner join (
    select b.*, dense_rank() over(partition by setid order by substr(course_list, 1, 6)) rn
    from b
) b on a.setid = b.setid and a.rn = b.rn
```

The first subquery sequentially ranks records having the same `setid`. The second subquery assigns the same rank to records that have the same `setid` and whose first 6 characters of `course_list` are identical. You can then `join` these two resultsets to get the results that you want.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=baa1c0bfa664a6d70c131c44906c2d2c)**:

```
SETID | SEL_GROUP | COURSELIST
:---- | :-------- | ---------:
KICAE | AA_01DBA  |  110011000
KICAE | AA_01DBA  |  110011200
KICAE | AA_01DBA  |  110011500
KICAE | AA_01DBA  |  110011530
KICAE | AA_02DHM  |  110021000
KICAE | AA_02DHM  |  110021200
KICAE | AA_02DHM  |  110021500
KICAE | AA_02DHM  |  110021530
```